# Thai Cave Rescue-Using trace gas detection to locate chimney entrances

Tags: civil-engineering, chemical-engineering

One of the potential ideas that was suggested for rescuing the Thai soccer team trapped in the cave is to locate a "chimney" or secondary entrance to the chamber where the team is trapped.  However, crews searching for this have not been able to find one that is suitable.

Suppose diver crews were to bring a rare chemical or isotope into the cave that is easy to detect in minute concentrations, and let it diffuse through the cave network.  Then, searchers on the surface could be supplied with equipment or animals that can detect this gas, and would have a way of knowing how close they are to entrances that are connected to the main cave.

For example, 2,4-dithiapentane is found in truffles, which pigs can sniff out.  So the surface team could be supplied with already-trained pigs.  However, its high mass density might make it unsuitable for diffusing through the cave network in a reasonable amount of time.

Could this be a reasonable approach to locating entrances?  What chemicals or detection methods would be suitable? Please cite a specific chemical/isotope and detection method with your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering Stack Exchange!  The first question is a good question.  The second one asking for specific chemicals or detection methods, is a bit broad for this site and will leave the question open for a broad range of opinions.  I would suggest rephrasing this question as "Please cite a specific chemical/isotope and detection method with your answer."

Answer (score 2):

Most underground mines in developed countries use a [stench gas system](http://www.minearc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Stench-Gas-System-Brochure.pdf) to alert the underground workforce of a danger, such as an underground fire, so that those who are underground can report to emergency safety bases (also known as fresh air bases).

The gas used is ethyl mercaptan, which smells of rotten onions. It's the same chemical that is added to methane, natural gas, supplies so that people can detect leaks of natural gas in domestic or industrial situations. Normally methane is odorless.

This chemical could be used in the cave in Thailand but it would be very unpleasant for everyone trapped underground because the smell lingers for a very long time, which could lead to people experiencing nausea and/or headaches if exposed to the gas for a long time.

Another flaw with using this method is that air flows through any underground system will be variable with most of the air and any stench gas following the path of least resistance. So not all, so called chimneys, may have stench gas go through them.

Other flaws include: if so called chimneys do exists they may be too narrow, or too steep, or have too many changes of direction (dog legs), or their ground conditions may not be safe for anyone to use.

Comment: And once it gets into the open air, the wind will blow it around - so even if you detect it, you still have to figure out where it came from. If you could put detectors "near the chimneys" to eliminate the wind, then you already know where they are!